# Check if a string contains the "\"

Tags: php

I am trying to see if the string contains `\` and if i put it like this

`$search4 = '\';` or `like $search4 = "\";` it won't work as this is incorrect.

This is my search function

```
function Search($search, $string){
$position = strpos($string, $search);
if ($position == true){
    return 'true';
}
else{
    return 'false';
}}
```

And i am calling it like that `echo Search($search4, $string);`

Comment: `$search4 = '\\'` will work

Comment: ``\`` is the escape character in PHP string literals. Thus it must be doubled.

Comment: Yes, backslash escapes the next character so you need to use two.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the \ by using 2 \. Because '\' is escaping the single quote and is giving you an error. The same will happend with double quotes.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

```
function Search($search, $string){
    $position = strpos($string, $search);
    if ($position == true){
        return 'true';
    }else{
        return 'false';
    }
}

$search = '\\';
print Search($search, "someString");
```